# Clique vs Complete Graph

Tags: graphs, terminology

Is there a difference between a complete graph and a clique topology? As far as I understand, both refer to graphs in which every possible edge between any two vertices is present. Is there a subtle difference between these two concepts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A complete graph is a graph with every possible edge; a clique is a graph or subgraph with every possible edge. That is, one might say that a graph "contains a clique" but it's much less common to say that it "contains a complete graph".

Answer (score 1):

A  clique is an induced subgraph that is itself complete graph.
What's an induced subgraph?
Ans: Given a graph, we pick a set of vertices and construct a subgraph. But now if we also select all edges that were incident on the selected set of vertices in the original graph, then we construct an induced subgraph. If this induced subgraph has an edge between all vertex pairs then its is complete.
So I think every complete graph can be thought of as an induced subgraph of some larger graph and hence every complete graph can be considered as a clique.

Answer (score 0):

From [1, page 5, Notation and terminology]:

> A graph is complete if all vertices are joined by an arrow or a line. A subset is complete if it induces a complete subgraph. A complete subset that is maximal (with respect to set inclusion) is called a clique.

So, in addition to what was described above, [1] says that a clique needs to be maximal.

[1] S. L. Lauritzen. Graphical Models. Oxford University Press, New York, NY, 1996.

Comment: This might vary from source to source.  I don't think this is the most common/standard definition of 'clique'.

Comment: I agree. I personally would use 'maximal clique' to avoid ambiguity. I just wanted to state that some sources use this definition of 'clique', which should be helpful for users coming from such sources.